# Get all microsft.vsts... from azure devops with python

Tags: python, azure-devops

Hi i have succeeded ton connect azure devops with python and retrieve data from system fields with wiql query.but i Can not execute programm and i got an error like this

> KeyError[Microsoft.vsts.common.acceptedcriteria] i do not understand where is the probleme because i get the value for priority and not for acceptedcriteria. what am i missing ? any help would be appreciated

Every time i exécuté this Quercy  i get this error

```
from vsts.vss_connection import VssConnection
from msrest.authentication import BasicAuthentication
import json
from vsts.work_item_tracking.v4_1.models.wiql import Wiql

def emit(msg, *args):
print(msg % args)

def print_work_item(work_item):
    emit(
        "{0} ,{1},{2},{3}".format(
            work_item.fields["System.WorkItemType"],
            work_item.id,
            work_item.fields["System.Title"],
            work_item.fields["Microsoft.VSTS.Common.AcceptanceCriteria"]
            work_item.fields["Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Priority"]
        )
    )

personal_access_token = 'xbxbxxbxhhdhdjdkdkddkdkdkdkdkdkkdkdkd'
organization_url = 'https://dev.azure.com/YourorgName'
# Create a connection to the org
credentials = BasicAuthentication('', personal_access_token)
connection = VssConnection(base_url=organization_url, creds=credentials)
wiql = Wiql(
        query="""select [System.Id],[Microsoft.VSTS.Common.AcceptanceCriteria],[System.Title],[System.WorkItemType],[Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Priority] From WorkItems """
    )

wit_client = connection.get_client('vsts.work_item_tracking.v4_1.work_item_tracking_client.WorkItemTrackingClient')
wiql_results = wit_client.query_by_wiql(wiql).work_items
if wiql_results:
        # WIQL query gives a WorkItemReference with ID only
        # => we get the corresponding WorkItem from id
        work_items = (
            wit_client.get_work_item(int(res.id)) for res in wiql_results
```

Answer (score 0):

As a simple answer, you can update your print function to

```
def print_work_item(work_item):
    emit(
        "{0} ,{1},{2}".format(
            work_item.fields["System.WorkItemType"],
            work_item.id,
            work_item.fields["System.Title"]
        )
    )
```

Some fields (like `Microsoft.VSTS.Common.AcceptanceCriteria` and `Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Priority`) may not be represented in some work item types. Therefore, before printing a field you have to check its availability in `fields` dictionary.